# What's the difference between `t.type` and `t.strict` in `io-ts`?

Tags: typescript

I thought that `t.strict` would throw on objects that do not strictly adhere to the definition, but to my surprise, extra properties not defined in a `t.strict` still pass validation. Anyone know the difference between `t.type` and `t.strict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about what you can validate, but what runtime object you end up with:

```
import * as T from "io-ts";

const Foo = T.type({a: T.number, b: T.string})
const Bar = T.strict({a: T.number, b: T.string})

const foo = Foo.decode({a: 100, b: "", c: true})
const bar = Bar.decode({a: 100, b: "", c: true})

console.log(foo);
console.log(bar); // No "c" property here
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/io-ts-playground-wkwtjt?file=package.json,index.ts)